How to animate Fusionchart angulargauge on each live update with feedData()?
I tried to use:
1.
chart: {
    ...
    animation: 1,
    animationDuration: 1,
    animationStart: 1
}

also:
dials: {
    dial: [{
        ...
        value: **50**
        animation: 1
    }]
}


setData() instead of feedData()
examples given from fusion chart documentation and fusionchartAI

In each try - chart animates only on initial render to the dial value 50. After feedData is used needle just jumps around without animation.
p.s. even on official documentation - live angular is jumping on each update after initial render without animation: https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes/angulargauge
